# fixed destination in google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Do you know if there is a way to have

```
var rendererOptions = {
draggable: true
};
```

which allows the user to move the markers (origin and destination),
but the destination marker fixed (user will not be able to move the marker)?

Comment: Store all your maker in array alone with a flag that says whether the marker was moved or not, then prevent the user from moving the pin a second time by playing with the movestart and moveend event.

Comment: and how do i do that?